# Dell R410 and X5690 wont boot

Tags: hardware, central-processing-unit, dell-poweredge, intel

I have an R410 that we opened up to upgrade from 2 x E5520 to 2 x X5690.

However after the upgrade network didnt work and we could not even get a monitor output. We tried swapping CPU positions and eventually pulled the processor out.

We since discovered we were running 1.2 bios and dell is up to 1.12. I couldnt get release notes between 1.2 and 1.9 so I am not sure if there was a fix to make the X5690 compatible.

Is there a problem with going from E series to X series on R410? Do I just need bios upgrade?

How do I tell if the CPU is faulty? they were used CPU's.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That was a pretty big shift from a lower-end Nehalem CPU to a high end Westmere CPU. I would have checked compatibility prior to purchasing. Tough lesson, but the CPUs aren't compatible with your platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [X5690](http://ark.intel.com/products/52576/Intel-Xeon-Processor-X5690-12M-Cache-3_46-GHz-6_40-GTs-Intel-QPI) has a TDP of 130 W which means it is unsupported with this server. See ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-r410_User%27s%20Guide6_en-us.pdf

That is something you could and should have learned before buying the CPUs.

Comment: Thank you for your help and the link. We made an assumption. All is not lost, we will put those processors into an R710 instead. So it looks from the data that we could purchase the X5675 which is compatible with the R410 with idrac upgrade (done) and bios upgrade. Were on 1.2 and they have a 1.12 bios upgrade available